# Get maximum of average subject marks using java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, code-snippets

I have class student as below

```
 class Student{
        Map<String,Integer> subjectMarks;
        String name;
        
        
        public Student(Map<String,Integer> subject, String name) {
            super();
            this.subjectMarks = subject;
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Map<String,Integer> getSubjectMarks() {
            return subjectMarks;
        }
        public void setSubjectMarks(Map<String,Integer> subject) {
            this.subjectMarks = subject;
        }
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
     }
```

In main method we add student object in arraylist as follow.

```
        ArrayList<Student> arr = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Map m1 = new HashedMap();
        m1.put("Maths",40);
        m1.put("Science",50);
        Map m2 = new HashedMap();
        m2.put("Maths",60);
        m2.put("Science",20);
        arr.add(new Student(m1, "RAJ"));
        arr.add(new Student(m2, "AMIT"));
```

can some help/guide me to find average marks of subject for each student and then get maximum from averge. I want help to write this snippet in java8

Comment: It would be nice to include what you are looking for in the output. Using your example, do you want 45 for RAJ and 40 for AMIT or do you want 50 for Maths and 35 for Science? It's also helpful to include your attempt to far and where you are stuck, especially since this looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: expected output is RAJ 45 and Amit 40 then get max avg marks out of both which will be  45.

Comment: I tried to get output I know following code which will give you avg by subject name `Map<String, Double> average= 
arr.stream().map(s -> s.getSubjectMarks()).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,  Collectors.averagingDouble(Entry::getValue)));` I want to get avg of marks per student name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not limit yourself to the idea of streams in Java 8 where you have to process a stream result directly into the next stream and so on... The efficiency might not be the best but consider to nest loops.

Start to think what you have: several marks for every `Student`. You want to find the average of these marks for every `Student`. You can reduce the problem to first think on how to get the average for one `Student`.

```
double average = student.getSubjectMarks().values().stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).average().orElse(0.0);
```

Even though your examples show only integer numbers, averages can also be floating point numbers.

Then, you would have to loop through all students and execute the procedure above for every student.

```
Map<String, Double> studentAverages = new HashMap<>();

arr.forEach(student -> {
    double average = student.getSubjectMarks().values().stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).average().orElse(0.0);
    studentAverages.put(student.getName(), average);
});
```

In the described implementation, the required averages are saved in the `Map` `studentAverages` which has the names of the students as a key and the average mark as a value.

You can then simply get the maximum integer from your list.

```
studentAverages.values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).max();
```

Some answers provide more sophisticated usages of streams. However, the code above is more readable. Furthermore, the data type `Object` is very general, difficult for further usage and error prone.

Comment: Thanks Felix for knowledge. will keep your suggestion in mind for other problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Felix noted in his answer, since you have a nested collection it is difficult to process in a single stream. You can use one stream to calculate the average for each student and another to calculate the max of the averages.

Start with a separate function to calculate the average for a student:

```java
private OptionalDouble calculateAverageMarks(Student student) {
    return student.getSubjectMarks().values().stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .average();
}
```

Note that you could add `.orElse(0.0)` (or some other value) to the pipeline if you wanted to return a `double`, but that wouldn't allow you to later distinguish between a student with all 0's and one not enrolled in any subjects.

Then you can collect the averages into a map.

```java
Map<String, OptionalDouble> averageMarks = arr.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, this::calculateAverageMarks));
```

Note that using `Student::getName` in the collector will throw if two students share the same name. You could use `Function.identity()` instead to ensure that each key will be distinct as long as you don't override `equals` in `Student`.

If you want, you can then remove students with no subjects

```java
averageMarks.values().removeIf(v -> !v.isPresent());
```

In Java 11, you can use `OptionalDouble::isEmpty` instead of the lambda.

Then you can map the values to a double stream and get the max

```java
OptionalDouble max = averageMarks.values().stream()
    .filter(OptionalDouble::isPresent) // In case you didn't remove the empty marks
    .mapToDouble(OptionalDouble::getAsDouble)
    .max();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using streams to solve this as you requested.

- stream the list of maps.
- put the name of the student and the average in an object array.

  - stream the values of the map and use the summaryStatistics to get the average.
- Then use maxBy with a comparator to get the maximum average.
- Then display it.

```
Object[] result = arr.stream().map(s -> new Object[] {
        s.getName(),
        s.getSubjectMarks().values().stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                .summaryStatistics().getAverage() })
        .max(Comparator.comparing(obj -> (double) obj[1]))
        .get();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Prints

```
[RAJ, 45.0]
```